# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent using passportjs/Express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

The error in question

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

**server.js**

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , expressSession = require('express-session')
    , server = require('http').createServer(app)
    , passport = require('passport')
    , local = require('passport-local').Strategy
    , md5 = require('md5')
    , util = require('util')
    , flash = require('connect-flash')
    , port = 80
    , url = require('url')
    , db = require('./db');

// optimization ================================================================
var compress = require('compression');
app.use(compress());

// configuration ===============================================================
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

// passport ====================================================================
passport.use(new local(
    function(username, password, done) {
        // asynchronous verification, for effect...
        process.nextTick(function () {
            db.findUserByName(username, function (err, user) {
                if (err) { done(err); }
                if (!user) { done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user: ' + username})}
                if (md5(password) == user.password) {
                    done(null, user);
                } else {
                    done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
                }
            });
        });
    }
));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.uuid);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    db.findUserByUUID(id, done);
});

// routes ======================================================================
require('./routes')(app, passport);

// launch ======================================================================
server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server started');
});
```

**routes.js**

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index', { num: 0, logged: false });
    });

    app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
        if (typeof req.user !== 'undefined') {
            // User is logged in.
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            req.user = false;
            var message = req.flash('error');
            if (message.length < 1) {
                message = false;
            }
            res.render('login', { logged: false, message: message });
        }
    });

    app.post('/login',
        passport.authenticate('local', {
            failureRedirect: '/login',
            failureFlash: true
        }),
        function(req, res) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    );

    app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });


};
```

**db.js**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db';

exports.findUserByName = function (username, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        var cursor = db.collection('players').find( { "name": username } );
        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
            if (doc != null) {
                console.log('YES');
                callback(false, doc)
            } else {
                console.log('NO');
                callback(false, null);
            }
            db.close();
        });

    });
};

var findUserByUUID = function(uuid, db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('players').find( { "uuid": uuid } );
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc != null) {
            callback(false, doc)
        } else {
            callback(false, null);
        }
    });
};
exports.findUserByUUID = function (uuid, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        findUserByUUID(uuid, db, function(err, data) {
            callback(err, data);
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

I understand that i'm calling done() twice, but when? I'm unable to find it.
I suppose that the problem is on the routes, but I don't know where.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent) and see if that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `passport.use()` handler, each time you call `done()`, you need to then `return` so that the code after it is not also executed.

Right now you have a series of `if` statements that can each call `done()`, but they aren't `if/else` statements so more than one condition you are testing for can be met and thus `done()` can be called more than once.

For example, change this:

```
if (!user) { done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user: ' + username})}
```

to this:

```
if (!user) { 
    done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user: ' + username});
    return;
}
```

And, change this:

```
if (err) { done(err); }
```

to this:

```
if (err) { 
    done(err); 
    return;
}
```

---

Or, you could make everything into `if/else if/else if/else` such that only one branch could ever execute.  The problem occurs when more than one of your `if` statements has its condition met and then is executed.

---

Now, your `findUserByName()` calls its callback in `cursor.each()` so it can call it multiple times which then causes you to call `done()` multiple times.

Comment: I've changed everything to an if/else if/else if/else statement, but I'm still getting the same error. I've posted the DB code.

Comment: @bernatixer - Your `findUserByName()` calls its callback in `cursor.each()` so it can call it multiple times which then causes you to call `done()` multiple times.